# swiftmailer with RFC 6530

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Has anyone tried to send mails with international characters (conforming to RFC 6530, e.g. 'john.dö@example.com') with swiftmailer?

I always get an Swift_RfcComplianceException with message 'Address in mailbox given [...] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'. I'm using the current stable release (5.2.2).

I opened an isssue at the swiftmailer github page: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/535